# Match and remove everything up to and including "=" in string with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Given the URL: `http://localhost:3000/test/tagger.html?id=31415` I need to strip everything up to and including the `=` sign, and set the value on the right of the equal sign into a TextBox field. I have the following which matches up to the equal sign, but keeps it. How can I remove it?

```
var url = "http://localhost:3000/test/tagger.html?id=31415"; 
var regex = /=.*/; // match '=' and capture everything that follows
var accountId = url.match(regex);
$(".accountNumber").val(accountId);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/x85mx3a0/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also simply use

```
var accountId = url.substr(url.indexOf("=") + 1); //Returns everything after `=`
```

**Edit**:

To do a check if `=` exists in the URL we can simply put an `if` like this:

```
if(url.indexOf("=") != -1){
  var accountId = url.substr(url.indexOf("=") + 1); //Returns everything after `=`
}
```

Comment: Chosen for simplicity. Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI: With this solution, if the URL contains no `=`, the whole URL will be shown. With my regex fix, no text will be shown since `m[1]` will not be populated. Not sure which behavior is expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a capturing group:

```
/=(.*)/
```

Or perhaps, even better solution is to check for the `id` numeric value with

```
/\bid=(\d+)/
```

And then access this value via Group 1:

```
var accountId = url.match(regex)[1];
```

See [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brjmra4e/1/)

```
var url = "http://localhost:3000/test/tagger.html?id=31415"; 
var regex = /\bid=(\d+)/; 
var accountId = url.match(regex)[1];
$(".accountNumber").val(accountId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = "http://localhost:3000/test/tagger.html?id=31415"; 
var regex = /=(.*)/; // match '=' and capture everything that follows
var accountId = url.match(regex);
$(".accountNumber").val(accountId[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class="accountNumber">
```

Capturing groups `=(.*)`

`accountId[1]` will capture content between parentheses

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://localhost:3000/test/tagger.html?id=31415"; 
var arr = url.split("=");
var val = arr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove everything up to and including the first '='

```
var regex = /^[^=]*=/; // match '=' and capture everything that follows
var accountId = url.replace(regex, '');
```